# Geometric measure of entanglement in example with GHZ state

Tags: quantum-entanglement

I'm learning about different possibilities to measure entanglement right now, and I'm struggling with the geometric measure. My question is probably quite trivial, but I can just not comprehend how the following example was calculated.

So, what I know is that if I have an $n$-partice pure state, in general: $$\lvert{\psi}\rangle = \sum_{p_1,p_2,\dots p_n} C_{p_1 \dots p_n}\lvert{p_n}^{(1)}\rangle \otimes \  \lvert{p_2}^{(2)}\rangle \otimes \dots \lvert{p_n}^{(n)}\rangle  $$
Then I have to find the closest seperable pure state $$\lvert\phi\rangle.$$ The measure is then $$ \Lambda = \max_{\phi} \lvert\langle\phi|\psi\rangle\rvert$$

In the given example, there is the GHZ-State: 
$$ \lvert \text{GHZ}\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} ( \lvert001\rangle + \lvert010\rangle + \lvert100\rangle) $$
And the solution should be $\Lambda=2/3$. But I do not know, how this is calculated. The result implies (so I think) that the relevant $\lvert\phi\rangle$, which creates the maximum value, is a linear combination of 3 states of which 2 are also in the GHZ-state. But a state like:
$$ \lvert\phi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} ( \lvert001\rangle + \lvert010\rangle + \lvert000\rangle ) $$ 
Is not separable in factors of the 3 separate Hilbert-spaces. What do I miss? Or which thing did I misunderstood?

Edit: relevant link to slides : http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/conf/simons-qcomputation/talks/wei.pdf
Definition on Slide 10, Example on Slide 14)

Comment: Although a good question in my opinion, you should consider to edit it to use `\lvert` and `\rangle` for dirac noation (see the [help page on notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation)) as this will make it much easier to read your question.

Comment: Where did you read this question and answer?

Comment: As example here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0212030v1.pdf
Page 2, bottom right. I also found presentation-slides from the same author with the same example and result, but I cannot find the link to this anymore.

Comment: Hmm, that paper isn't particularly lucid, is it! I think my answer was incorrect, I've removed it

Comment: @Djoser42 Hi I am interested in learning about multipartite entanglement, do you have any other recommendations for basic notes which you found useful in outlining ideas of multipartite entanglement?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sketch of the calculation, take:

$$ \lvert\phi\rangle = \lvert\phi_1\rangle \otimes \lvert\phi_2\rangle \otimes \lvert\phi_2\rangle $$

The most general form of each component is

$$ \lvert\phi_i\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u_i^2+v_i^2}}\begin{bmatrix}
u_i+iv_i
\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

where, $i=1,2,3$ and $u_i$ and $v_i$ are real

Writing the (square of the) inner product $\Lambda$ with and differentiating it with respect to the $u_i$'s and the $v_i$'s we obtain 6 equations, each couple of  equations of the $u_i$'s and $v_i$'s can be subtracted to obtain linear equations whose final result implies that:

$$u_1=u_2=u_3 \doteq u $$

and

$$v_1=v_2=v_3 \doteq v $$

substituting thse results in the expression for $\Lambda$, we get

$$\Lambda = \frac{\sqrt{3r}}{(\sqrt{1+r})^3}$$

where $ r = u^2+v^2$

This expression attains its maximum at $r = \frac{1}{2}$ with $\Lambda = \frac{2}{3}$